# Problem with showing section titles swift

Tags: swift, uitableview

Here is my code for showing titles for sections :

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String!{
        if section == 0 {
            return sections[0]
        } else if (section == 1){
            return sections[1]
        } else {
            return ""
        }
    }
```

I have a list for sections names called "sections". But the titles aren't showing up on the simulator. Thanks !

Comment: You're returning `String` where are you setting that `String` at? Only required if you're using a custom header. We need a bit more to go on to help resolve this issue.

Comment: here :  var sections = ["Customer", "Items", "Add new"]

Comment: Are you using a custom view for your section headers?

Comment: Post your entire code related to displaying `headerInSection`.

Comment: What's your Swift version, because that's not the current Swift version method. It's now `func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String?` vs `func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String!{`. If you remove it, start rewrite it and let the autocompletion help you?

Comment: It's also possible he included `tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection..)` and if so it will prioritize of the `titleForHeaderInSection`

Comment: It worked thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the [minimal-required-code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to show how tableView with header title works. `Copy/Paste` this on your playground and check to see how it works:

```swift
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    var sections = ["Section 1", "Section 2", "Section 3"]

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        sections.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        sections[section]
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ViewController())
PlaygroundPage.current.needsIndefiniteExecution = true
```